# passing props to the component conditionally in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass a props to the component only after it full fills a certain condition .
I have this Paper component inside return of render in react.
I want to pass the onScroll only when a condition is there.

```
<Paper className={classes.root}  onScroll={this.loadMoreClasses}>
```

What i want to achieve

```
<Paper className={classes.root}  organizationname!==null ?onScroll={this.loadMoreClasses} :null>
```

want onScroll to happen only when organizationname is not definedthere

Answer (score 4):

You could pass it like this:

```
<Paper
    className={classes.root}
    onScroll={organizationname !== null ? this.loadMoreClasses : null}
/>
```

That way your `Paper` component receives the `onScroll` listener when the organisation name it set, but does not receive it otherwise. You need to make sure that the `Paper` component treats the `onScroll` prop as optional, otherwise you'll get errors from it trying to call a method that doesn't exist.

An alternative would be to always provide an `onScroll` prop and move the condition to your `getMoreClasses` method, making it do nothing if the organisation name is not set.

Comment: This is more efficient onScroll={!oranizationname ? this.loadMoreClasses : null}

Comment: Thanks mate .I didn't remember though i have used it somewhere for sure .

Comment: Agreed. I thought of using ! So that it validates other things like undefined instead of explicit check specifically for null

Comment: [Deleted my earlier comment because it had an error but was past the edit timeout. This was a reply to Hemadri's first comment]. Good point. Not really more efficient, but a bit neater, although you'll need to flip the `if` and `else`. Worth noting that it reduces the precision of the check from "is not null" to "is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)". That's probably fine in this case because organisation names probably aren't zero/empty strings/etc., but the question used `!== null` so I kept it the same.